# How to set the default controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm using the Laravel PHP framework and am wondering about a few things. The default `application/routes.php` file contains this:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
});
```

This just outputs the view, but how do I call a controller from there?

I can delete the entire route above and replace it with `Route::controller('home')` which seems to use the home controller on the default URL (i.e. `example.com/`). But any other controller like `Route::controller('article')` doesn't work, only on `example.com/article`. How would I set the article controller as the default?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just pass the controller as a string, with `@` between the class name and the method name:

```
Route::get('/', 'article@index');
```

Read [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#controller-routing) (scroll to the example by the title **Registering a route that points to a controller action**).

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed that part of the page. What about the `home` thing though? Is `Route::get('/', 'home@index')` the same as `Route::controller('home')` ?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - Nope. `Route::get('/', 'home@index')` will only register the index method, and only on the `/` route. `Route::controller('home')` will register all its methods, mapped to their respective URLs.

Comment: How would the latter work? If you register an entire controller to `/` then doesn't `/example` become ambiguous, between a controller called 'example' vs an 'example' method on the home controller.

Comment: You can't register an entire controller to `/`. To register a route, you register one specific method. If you want to register an entire controller, you use `Route::controller('controller_name')`.

Comment: What I'm saying is, if you register the home controller using `Route::controller('home')`, it becomes the default controller on `/` (unless `/` is already specified). Or at least, the index method of the home controller is registered.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - I'm not following you. What is the specific problem that you're trying to solve (or understand)?

Comment: I'm just getting confused about the home controller. If you have `Route::controller('home')` and nothing else in your routes file, the home controller becomes the default and is available on the root URL (`/`) as well as the expected `home/`. However, that's not the case if you just put `Route::controller('article')` and nothing else, it is only available on `/article`. (P.S. don't worry, you've answered my main question.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22986/discussion-between-joseph-silber-and-disgruntledgoat)

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Read the Laravel documentation on routing and controllers. Throughly. The questions you’re asking are answered in there.

Comment: @Martin This is a 5 year old question. It was asked at a time when the docs were not as good as they are now (Laravel 4 or even L3). And my question from the comments is *not* answered there any more since Laravel removed controller routes.

Answer (score 2):

The "`/`" is special location and you can set it via `Route::get('/','home@index')`.

For all other actions on home controller you will have **urls** such has "`/home/action1`" or "`/home/action2`".

I am just trying to make you understand that there is no benefit and need of making any controller assign to "`/`".

I hope I am clear with my reply. Again this is not an attempted answer to your question but a suggestion for you if you are stuck with route handling. I was at the same stage where you are few days back :)

Comment: This is an old post but it's one of the top in Google so I am commenting for that reason. If anyone finds this, when you set a Route::controller('/', 'Controller') you break all other links which is why it is not a good idea to use the default '/' for a controller route

Answer (score 0):

`Route::get('/', [LandingPage::class, 'index']);`

This worked for me.

Also don't forget to add
`use App\Http\Controllers\LandingPage;` in `routes/web.php`

Comment: This question has already been answered, and an answer was accepted.

Comment: If you want to add more context or advice, please use the comment section. You will get access to this feature soon by earning more reputation :-)